# auto increment column alongside with primary key

Tags: mysql, database

I need to sort my query result by the time that they are inserted
the easiest way Is to store an `auto_increment` key with each row to sort data by It
but also need to have a *random Id* generated as `primary_key`
It would be something like the following:

```
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| sortId(auto_increment) | id(primary) | content(varchar) |
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| 0                      | 23245       | some text        |
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| 1                      | 94655       | some text        |
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| 2                      | 59413       | some text        |
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

so I'll be able to load my data sorted by `sortID`
but as I see In `phpmyadmin`, I'm not allowed to add an `auto_increment` column when I've a `primary_key` in my table.
why Is that happening and how can I solve It?
Is there any way better to sort query results coming from database?

thanks.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use it normally - setting `sortId` as a primary index with auto-increment, and `id` being an unique index?

Comment: I had no idea about that , can I use unique indexed as foreign keys?

Comment: Sure, any index can be used as a foreign key. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about setting foreign key constraints, they can be set on any indexed field, so I suggest you set your `sortId` to be a primary auto-incremented index, and `id` a unique index.

Unless you really have a good reason to go against this usual approach.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sortID column from **INT** to **TIMESTAMP** and set its default value to TIMESTAMP. It will insert current timestamp every time row is created and you will not only be able to sort them the same way you would sort integers but also you will know when creation happened.

Comment: such a good Idea. but It's actually wasting storage space and decreasing performance . I don't really need the generation time. thanks anyway